# Как установить библиотеку com.android.support:design:25.3.0

Tags: android, android-studio

Изучаю книгу "Head First. Программирование для Android 2-е изд."
Остановилась на 12 главе. Там, где требуется добавить библиотеку com.android.support:design:25.3.0
Android Studio больше не добавляет старые библиотеки, но в интернете пишут что добавить можно через Google Maven.

"Вы можете продолжать использовать библиотеку поддержки. Исторические артефакты (версия 27 и более ранние и упакованные как android.support.*) останутся доступными в Google Maven. Однако разработка всех новых библиотек будет происходить в библиотеке AndroidX"

Прoписываю в файле build.gradle(:app):

```
dependencies {
      implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
      ...
}
```

Android Studio выдает ошибку: "Version 28 (intended for Android Pie and below) is the last version of the legacy support library, so we recommend that you migrate to AndroidX libraries when using Android Q and moving forward. The IDE can help with this: Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX..."

Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX..." - тоже ничего не дает...

Помогите кто знает и кому не сложно...

Comment: Ставьте 28 версию, если уж так хочется эту библиотеку.

Comment: В смысле 28 версию этой библиотеки? Да я ставила, в том числе и 28...

Comment: dependencies { implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0' ... } и тоже самое

Comment: тогда используйте AndroidX, зачем вам библиотека, которая уже не поддерживается.

Comment: Для изучения книги "Head First. Программирование для Android 2-е изд."!!!

Comment: так вам книгу изучать или программирование под андроид? для чего вам библиотека, которая уже не используется???

Comment: "Вы можете продолжать использовать библиотеку поддержки. Исторические артефакты (версия 27 и более ранние и упакованные как android.support.*) останутся доступными в Google Maven. Однако разработка всех новых библиотек будет происходить в библиотеке AndroidX" - читаем внимательно "ОСТАНУТСЯ ДОСТУПНЫМИ В Google Maven"

Comment: мне книгу изучать...

Comment: Ок. Какая у вас ошибка? То, что вы написали в вопросе, это не ошибка, а предупреждение. Может, у вас уже и загрузилась библиотека, а вы тут паникуете.

Comment: "Android Studio выдает ошибку: "Version 28 (intended..."

Comment: Это что, не ошибка? Не грузится библиотека, что тут еще поделаешь...

Comment: Нет, это не ошибка. Это предупреждение. Или информация для принятия к сведению, если хотите.

Comment: В книге написано: "Загрузите библиотеку...". Библиотека не грузится. Андроид подчеркивает красным. Пусть это не ошибка, только расскажите мне что я должна делать на следующем шаге. Учитывая, что мне все таки нужно ее загрузить.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137125/discussion-between-alice-magic-and-).

Comment: В книге написано: "Загрузите библиотеку...". Библиотека не грузится. Андроид подчеркивает красным. Пусть это не ошибка, только расскажите мне что я должна делать на следующем шаге. Учитывая, что мне все таки нужно ее загрузить.

Comment: Надо понизить версию sdk в приложении (targetSdkVersion, compileSdkVersion) до 28..Это в build.gradlee.

Comment: Браво!!! Михаил, вы мне жизнь спасли! А я уж думала бросить)))

Comment: но... в итоге новое сообщение: 
Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx.* can not be combined but found com.android.support:design:28.0.0 and androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2 incompatible dependencies

Comment: Похоже тебе проще будет создать новый проект в андроид студии. Думаю это из за того что мигрировалась на андроидХ (у тебя в описании есьб "Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX..."), и возможно как то криво/не полностью.  Ну и эникейщик, выше, тоже тебе плохого не советовал - вряд ли тебе эта библиотека поддержки пригодится. Упорство - это конечно уже пол дела, но гибкость - это тоже не мало.

Comment: Меня напугала фраза "обнаружены несовместимые зависимости com.android.support:design:28.0.0 и androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2"... и я забила на поиск... ЗАТО, я нашла все недостающие библиотеки в appcompatе... и дело продолжается!!! А Вам и Эникейщику моя особая благодарность что не бросили! :)